Spinning a rope conundrum
Sometimes I will take a rope or string and spin it in the air to see what will happen. Now usually, if I am spinning it vertically, the end of the rope will extend outwards due to Newton's first law, making it want to continue its original straight-line path, but being pulled in a circle due to tension.

Sorry for the artist rendition quality, I don't draw very well :)
However, very strangely, when I spin the rope horizontally (from rest) this happens:

(You can try it out too with any string of reasonable mass and length. I found that 2 ft or more of string works best.)
The string seems to split into thirds:

I am not sure why this happens, and why it only happens when I start spinning the string from rest. If I give the end of the string a bit of initial velocity, or start spinning it vertically and rotate it to be horizontal, then it spins as normal with the rope extended outwards. Having solved problems relating to spinning strings and rods like this in AP Mechanics, this does not make sense to me: Why is the end of the middle third (the yellow dot in the graphic above) directly under my hand? Why does starting from rest have anything to do with rotation? If anything, why split the string into thirds and not halves where the center of mass is?

You are exciting standing "circularly polarized" waves in the rope. If you continue to spin at a faster frequency, you can create even more "nodes" in the rope (stable points of intersection below the center line). Because the rope tension is nonconstant down the length of the rope, the wavelength also changes.
